# Is opening stata do file in main window possible?

Tags: window, stata, program-entry-point

I'm new to stata and I would love to attach the do file editor to the main stata window (were the history command and variables tabs live). Ideally I'd like it to replace the command tab, similar to how it works in R. I find it really annoying to always have to open 2 windows.

Is that possible?

Comment: A Do-file-editor is just like a new script window in R which is distinct from the prompt. You cannot replace the command tab / window in Stata since that is equivalent to the prompt ">" in R where you can interactively execute the commands.

Comment: I hit enter prematurely. The "Command" window is considered a docking window.So you can hide it or make it into a tab. However, the Do-file editor window is a specialized window and treated as a non-dockable one by design and cannot be brought into the main Stata window. Read more  in this pdf document. https://www.stata.com/manuals13/gsw2.pdf

Comment: @sreedta That looks like the basis of a good answer to me. It's a Google quirk that the manuals for Stata 13 show up on a simple search but https://www.stata.com/manuals/gsw2.pdf is (always, I believe) the latest version, not that this key detail has changed so far as I know.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the heads up. I usually lookup help from within Stata itself. So I will add the link you provided as a favorite for my own reference.